# Windows 7, excel and word 2010 how get RID of Sharepoint popup window?

Tags: 2010, excel

When using Excel (and possibly Word) this irritating popup window appears requesting some kind of password.  I want to get RID of this window and get rid of Sharpoint, whatever it is.

Comment: Is this happening with all Excel documents or just one? We really need a little more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting SharePoint password prompts when opening office apps, then there is some reference to SharePoint in your environment.  I would suggest contacting your IT department (if applicable) to help understand and resolve the issue.